# New limit on synonyms for entities in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a project with an entity with 200 synonyms last Friday and it worked. Monday morning, I get the error that only 100 synonyms are allowed.

The dialogflow quota help page still shows 200 words. Is there some setting that can be changed?

Comment: the limit is 200 "entities & synonyms per entity type".  Does the combination of entities and synonyms per entity type exceed 200?  What error message are you seeing?  can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I can't post the screenshot because my 'reputation' here isn't 10.
But, the exact error is: 
"Request contains an invalid argument.
The number of synonyms should not be more than: 100"